# How to convert a char to its ascii decimal value?

Tags: c

I need to take a keyboard input letter, and save that letter's decimal value as an integer.
How can I do that with scanf ?

Comment: Read a single letter using [scanf](http://linux.die.net/man/3/scanf) and then convert it into an integer using [atoi](http://linux.die.net/man/3/atoi) functions.

Comment: When you say "save that letter's decimal value", do you expect `"1"` to be ave as `1` or as its ASCII character code such as `49`.?  If your read `"$"`, what value or error message would you want?

Answer (score 2):

I just figured out myself.

if I want to store the decimal value of 'z'

I can just do  int value='z'-'a'+ 97

This is what I wanted to know.

Comment: Actually, `'a' == 97`. Thus, the expression `int value = 'z' - 'a' + 97` is the same expression as `int value = 'z'`. Which is what I said in my answer. In addition to that, the variable `value` doesn't need to be int, which is 4 bytes long. You can do the same work using a `char`, which is 1 byte long.

Answer (score 1):

This code reads a char from keyboard (`stdin`) using `scanf()`, stores it in byte-sized variable `c` of type `char`, and then prints its ASCII decimal value as an `int` to `stdout` :

```
char c;    
scanf("%c", &c);    
printf("%d", c);
```

Comment: but how can I save that as integer value?

Comment: `char c` is an 8-bit integer value (1 bit for sign actually). If you take `A` from keyboard, then `printf("%d", c)` is going to print 65, and `printf("%d" c + 1)` is going to print 66, which is decimal ASCII code for `B`.

Comment: but I need to store this value.

Comment: Well, it's stored in `c`.

Comment: let's say I have int num[10]  and I want to store z in num[0]. How can I do that ?

Comment: Do you mean letter 'z' or some variable named `z` ? It's `num[0] = 'z';` for the first case and `num[0] = z;` for the second case. Also, array `num[10]` can be of type `char`.

Comment: By store, do you mean in a variable or something like saving it to a file?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to output the ASCII value, simply `printf()` with the `%d` format string.

```
char ch = 'a';
printf("%d", a); // should be 97
```